# Postgresql convert 1200 to 1.2K

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to convert 1200 to 1.2K with Postgres like the Rails helper (`number_to_human`) method does?

```
number_to_human(1200, format: '%n%u', units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M', billion: 'B' })
# "1.2K"

number_to_human(1200000, format: '%n%u', units: { thousand: 'K', million: 'M', billion: 'B' })
# "1.2M"
```

Comment: `pg_size_pretty` would convert `1200000` to `1172 kB` - is that good enough?

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I saw something like that, but that would give me different results.

Comment: Seems, you'll need to create custom function/procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately "pg_size_pretty" will probably not work. It returns results in terms of 1024 (2^10) not powers of 10.